# SQL Query - Rows to Columns but without pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need an efficient way to convert the data returned in rows to columns for a football database I'm working on.

2 tables, one holding fixtures, one holding predictions.

[Fixtures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D8c0.jpg):

[image]

[Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esw5f.jpg)

[image]

I would like the data in those two table returned as follows (Can't post another link, but this query will give you an idea):

```
SELECT  1 as UserID, 
    2 as [Stoke vs Man United], 
    1 as [Bournemouth vs Crystal Palace], 
    2 as [Swansea vs West Brom],
    1 as [Chelsea vs Watford],
    3 as [Liverpool vs Leicester],
    1 as [Tottenham vs Norwich],
    2 as [Aston Villa vs West Ham]
```

The problem is, each week, the chosen teams will change so I couldn't get a pivot query to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `I couldn't get a pivot query to work.` Show your trial, tag question properly (SQL Server) and prepare http://sqlfiddle.com. Anyway this question is 1001th duplicate of the same problem pivot/dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to know about to make this work.

1. [**Dynamic Pivot**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-dynamic-way)
2. [**sp_executesql**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Example

```
-- Param Definitions
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @WeekNo INT = 6,
        @UserID INT = 1,
        @Params NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@Week INT, @User INT'

-- Dynamic Column Names
SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(HomeTeamName + ' vs ' + AwayTeamName)
FROM    usr_SS_Fixtures
WHERE   WeekNo = @WeekNo

-- Dynamic SQL
SET @Sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        pred.UserId,
        pred.ResultCode,
        CONCAT(HomeTeamName,'' vs '', AwayTeamName) AS Teams
    FROM
        usr_SS_Fixtures fix
        JOIN usr_SS_Predictions pred ON fix.EventID = pred.EventID AND fix.WeekNo = pred.WeekNo
    WHERE 
        fix.WeekNo = @Week
        AND pred.UserID = @User
) t
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(ResultCode)
    FOR Teams IN (' + @Columns + ')
) p
'

-- Executes the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, @Params, @Week = @WeekNo, @User = @UserID
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04d2d/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting variation on the normal *dynamic pivot* problem, due to the *known-in-advance* maximum number of games, that makes one possible solution a little simpler. Try the SQL below; it creates a *first row* that contains the desired column headings, which may be sufficient for simple display purposes.

```
declare @weekNo as int = 6
       ,@UserID as int = 1;   
with
fixture(UserID, EventID, [Value], GameNo) as (
    select -1, EventID, AwayTeamName + ' at ' + HomeTeamName
        , row_number() over (partition by WeekNo order by EventID)
    from usr_SS_Fixtures
),
prediction(UserID, EventID, [Value], GameNo)  as (
    select UserID, EventID, ResultCode
        , row_number() over (partition by WeekNo order by EventID)
    from usr_SS_Predictions
),
data as (
    select
         WeekNo, UserID
        ,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
    from (
        select WeekNo, UserID, EventID, [Value] from fixture
        union all
        select WeekNo, UserID, EventID, [Value] from prediction
    ) T
    pivot (
        max([Value]) for GameNo in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
    ) pvt
)
select
    UserID,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
from data
where WeekNo = @WeekNo
order by
    UserID
```